# Array of Arrays in PHP from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get results from a MySQL database (for invoices) that includes multiple rows with multiple columns in each row.  The database has three columns: Date (text), Hours (text), and Charged (boolean).  I am trying to get an array of arrays to feed into a PHP script where the final product would be the same as this:

```
$invoice = array(array("date1","hours1"),array("date2","hours2"));
```

I currently have the following code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
$condb = mysql_select_db("$db_name");
...
120 | $sql = "SELECT date,hours FROM 'c1_log' WHERE charged=0";
121 | $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
122 | $invoice = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

When I run the code I get the following PHP error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in .../dbcon.php on line 122
```

Is there an alternate function to `mysql_fetch_array()` that would work?

Comment: You shouldn't use single quotes for table names. Use backticks or just don't surround them. That's what is causing the error probably.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem.  However, it's only returning the first row.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also, it's not returning an array of arrays as I expected, but instead a single array (the first row).

Comment: If you want to get all the rows from an SQL query you must use a loop:
```$invoices = array(); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { $invoices[] = $row; }``` Or, if you use PDO, you can just use the ``fetchAll()`` method. I'd strongly suggest this last option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a fetch_all function for mysql you need to get it programmatically:

```
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
if ( ! mysql_select_db("$db_name")) {
  echo "Could not select DB: " . mysql_error();
  exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT date,hours FROM `c1_log` WHERE charged=0";

if ( ! ($result = mysql_query($sql,$con) ){
  echo "Query error: " . mysql_error();
  exit;
}

// use fetch_assoc so that you end up with array
// keys as the column names not numbers
while ($invoice[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

//While loop is used to get all results from the query into an array.


//To check your output:
// (if in a browser echo a pre tag for nice formatting)
echo "<pre>";
print_r($invoice);
echo "</pre>";

//Should give you something like this..
//$invoice = array(0=>array("date"=>"","hours"=>""),1=>array("date"=>"","hours"=>""));
```

Link to [fetch_assoc](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Also note, these native mysql_* functions are being phased out. It would be wise to start using a framework or at least PDO.

Comment: I get the following error when running that: `Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''c1_log' WHERE charged=0' at line 1`

Comment: yea sorry, just noticed, replace the single quotes with backticks: `

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT date,hours FROM c1_log WHERE charged=0";
```

Edit: After reading your comment above, remember the mysql_fetch_array should be a loop. So try this:

```
while ($invoice = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     var_dump($invoice )
}
```